# Online/offline data updating mobile best practices

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, cordova, devexpress

I have a requirement to create a mobile app that has the ability to queue up records that need to be saved when no internet connection is available and update the data via web api when a connection is available in our SQL Server DB.

I'm trying to avoid having a local version of the DB on the device which I've seen some others recommend in other questions on stackoverflow.

The approach I'm going with right now is to try and save the records in a local store (JSON) while there is no connection.  Then to try and hook in some event to know when the connection has been re-established to update my data to SQL Server.

I'm just wondering what the best practices are around this? Are there issues with my current way of trying to solve this problem?

We are using DevExpress's DevExtreme mobile solution with Visual Studio 2012 and Cordova PhoneGap.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the JSON data that you want to store, likely to get?

Depending on your answer, you could store it (the JSON data) in localStorage and then write it next time the device is connected.

Comment: Not very big in the current scenario.  Could be a dozen records or so with five to 10 fields each.

Comment: Then I would suggest using localStorage in a JSON format. I have used the localStorageDB plugin (https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) to make things easier.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back.